# Image Display on Hover

Tags: javascript, css

Code is for displaying an image during a hover.

In addition to not getting the images to display while hovering, I am getting a white border on the top (about 17px) and right side of the image.

Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

http://jsfiddle.net/wfpzLv8n/

```
  .nav-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 770px;
    background: #111;
    position: relative;
  }

  .nav-wrap .img-place {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 5;
  }

  .nav-wrap .nav li {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
    position: relative;
    z-index: 6;
    list-style: none;
  }

  .nav-wrap .nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 48px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: "Thin";
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    margin: -12px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 70px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }

  .nav-wrap .nav:hover li a {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }

  .nav-wrap .nav li a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    padding-left: 95px;
    font-weight: 600;
  }

  .nav-wrap .bg1 {
    background-image: url("http://www.photography-match.com/views/images/gallery/Ghandrung_Village_and_Annapurna_South_Nepal_Himalaya.jpg");
    background-size: 120%;
    opacity: 0.3;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s forwards;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s forwards;
    -ms-animation: fadein 2s forwards;
    -o-animation: fadein 2s forwards;
    animation: fadein 2s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 11s forwards ease-out;
    animation: mymove 11s forwards ease-out;
  }

  ` @keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  @-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  @-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  @-o-keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0% {
      top: -12px;
    }
    100% {
      top: -240px;
    }
  }

  @keyframes mymove {
    0% {
      top: -12px;
    }
    100% {
      top: -240px;
    }
  }

  .nav-wrap .bg2 {
    background-image: url("http://travspire.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Glimpse_of_hampi_main.jpg");
    background-size: 125%;
    opacity: 0.4;
    animation: bgani 7s linear forwards;
  }

  .nav-wrap .bg3 {
    background-image: url("http://lh5.ggpht.com/_nFOgRvQfbY4/SqDwU31NB8I/AAAAAAAAATE/Jo1zuHhJaDA/s1600/IMG_4278.JPG");
    background-size: 130%;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s forwards ease-out;
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s forwards ease-out;
    -ms-animation: fadein 3s forwards ease-out;
    -o-animation: fadein 3s forwards ease-out;
    animation: fadein 3s forwards ease-out;
  }

  @keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  @-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  @-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  @-o-keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  @keyframes bgani {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      background-size: 100%;
    }
    15% {
      opacity: 0.3;
    }
    100% {
      background-size: 125%;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: It's also worh mentioning that your HTML is invalid. `ul` can only have `li` as direct children. No paragraphs or breaks.

Comment: Adding a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to the code will help in solving the problem.

Comment: --Paulie, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks.

Comment: Musically, just added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jsFiddle was messed up, that's all. You shouldn't put the `<style></style>` tags in the CSS area, and you shouldn't put the `<script></script>` tags in the JavaScript area. Also, to include jQuery, you need to include it as an external resource, which is a section in the left sidebar. You put your resource URL in the text box, and click the plus button at its right. Here's a fixed version, with your HTML cleaned up too.
http://jsfiddle.net/xchrt5db/

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're new to jsfiddle? I've formatted it correctly now, is that working?

```
$('.nav li a').hover(function() {
  $('.img-place').toggleClass($(this).data('target'));
});
$('.nav-wrap .img-place, .nav-wrap').height($(window).height());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/wfpzLv8n/2/

Comment: Yes, new. Thanks. Still the 17px border.